# Does Azure DevOps remove quotation marks when setting a pipeline variable via a script?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I have to set an array for an ARM Template within my Azure DevOps pipeline. I set my variable like this:

```
$foo = '["' + 'bar' + '"]'
Write-Host $foo
#######Assign Variables with Correct Value in pipeline
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=fooVariableInPipeline]$foo"
```

The $foo value is fine which would be ["bar"] as expected.
But when I inspect the value in the next tasks after setting the variable, it would remove the quotation marks and show the value as [bar].

This is rather strange and I am wondering if its me or is it a bug? Any workarounds?

For the time being, I have updated my file directly using powershell code.

Comment: Can you show us what _the next tasks_ look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does Azure DevOps remove quotation marks when setting a pipeline variable via a script?

This issue does not come from azure devops, but depends on the syntax of your next task.

If I use the `command line` task to output that variable, it works fine:

```
echo $(fooVariableInPipeline)
```

The output:

[image]

**However**, if we use the `powershell` task to output it, it will remove quotation marks:

```
Write-Host "fooVariableInPipeline is $(fooVariableInPipeline)"
```

The output:

[image]

To resolve this issue, we need to surround the variable with **single quotes** to make it a **literal string**, like:

```
$Testfoo= '$(fooVariableInPipeline)'

Write-Host "Testfoo is $Testfoo"
```

Now, it works fine:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a here-string:

```bsh
$foo = @"
    ["bar"]
"@
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue myself.

A workaround is to use two double quotes.

In powershell:

```
$foo -replace '"', '""'
```